# Java code or php code to display entire database in a alert pop up box in html web page

Tags: java, php, jquery, html, mysql

Hey guys i am making a webpage airline booking for my project and on the home page i have kept a few text boxes and when i hit submit button it displays the data in the table which is already on the page .. but instead i want to display the entire table in a popup screen.. so when i hit the search button it should search the database and show the available flights to book in a table on a pop up box ...

This the basic code on which the data is displayed on the page .. i want to change this to display it in a java or php popup box which could have some design to look a bit attractive .. plz help

```
 <?php
 include ('airlineDB2.php');
  ?>
  <html>
  <head>

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="style.css"></link> 

</head>
 <body>
 <form  action="" name="formdownload" method="post">
  <center>
       <div class="page">
                         <div class="header">
                          <div class="logo">
                          <img src="bankimg.jpg">

   <div class="bnkname">
   &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<h1><font color="blue"    size="10" font face="Lucida Handwriting">AIRINDIA Airline Reservation</font></h1>
 </div>


 <div class="linkspart">

   <div class="sublinks">
   <a href="airline.php">Home </a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
  <a href="search.php">Search Flight</a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp

 <a href="about.php">About us</a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp

 <a href="help.php">Help/FAQ</a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp

   </div>
  </div>


   <div class="bodypart">
 <div class="regi">
<table>
  <tr><td colspan=2><h1>Domestic Flights</h1></td></tr></br>
      <td height=50> From:</td><td><input type="From" name="from" size=30/>
        <tr><td height=50>To: </td><td><input type="To" name="to" size=30/>
        <tr><td><input name="submit" type="submit" value ="Search"></tr></td>
        <table border="1" align="center" id="table1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th>Flight No</th>
                <th>Flight Company</th>
                <th>Plane Type</th>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>To</th>
            </tr>
            <center>

            <?php

            $submit = @$_POST['submit'];
            $from = @$_POST['from'];
            $to = @$_POST['to'];
            if($submit)
             {
              if($from==true)
                {
                 $select=mysql_query("select * from flight where ffrom='$from' and tto='$to'");
                 while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($select))

                 {
                    $FlightNo = $row1['flightno'];
                    $FlightCompany=$row1['flightcompany'];
                    $PlaneType = $row1['planetype'];
                    $From =$row1['ffrom'];
                    $To =$row1['tto'];

             ?>


            <tr>

            <td width="90" align="center">
                <?php echo $FlightNo;?>
            </td>
            <td width="90" align="center">
                <?php echo $FlightCompany;?>
            </td>
            <td width="90" align="center">
                <?php echo $PlaneType;?>
            </td>
            <td width="90" align="center">
                <?php echo $From;?>
            </td>
            <td width="90" align="center">
                <?php echo $To;?>
            </td>

            </tr>
            <?php }

            echo"enter a place to go:";}}?>
            </table>

  </table>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>


</div>

</center>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right you want this page in a popup? So you can use:

`<iframe src=''>  <iframe>`

You need to put this in the page you want the other page to popup. You now need to design a popup (with css and javascript/jquery) so it pops up when you want. Or when you want.

Css:

`.popUp{
    display: none;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: -300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    z-index: 100;
    background: black;
    margin-right: 10px;
}`

Jquery:

`

```
  function popAuto(button,div){
   button.on('click', function(){
        if(!div.is(':visible')){

                div.fadeIn();
            }else{

                div.fadeOut();
            }
           });
        }
```

`

button = div where you click on or the thing you click on.

div = the div you want to popup.

Hope this helped